# Missing SDK in target - iphoneos5.0

Tags: ios, xcode, sdk, target

I'm using Xcode 4.4.1. I'm getting this warning:

```
Missing SDK in target MyApp iphoneos5.0
```

I want to target iOS 5.0 and up. Where should I look to fix this?

In Target, Build Settings, Base SDK is set to iphoneos5.0.

EDIT: Furthermore, if I set the base SDK to latest iOS (5.1), does that mean that users running 5.0 will not be able to install the app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means your build settings are incorrect.  You set the string to "iphoneos5.0" which doesn't exist anymore.  You will now be compiling against "iphoneos5.1".  Instead you should simply choose "Latest iOS" (= "iphoneos") To have the compiler select automatically.

Users will still be able to run your app on any version above your app's *target* version (assuming you didn't use any libraries that don't run on those lower versions).

Comment: Thanks. So you are referring to ios Deployment Target in Project/Info right?